# Controller belonging to render helper gets reset if passed a model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I noticed a behavior in Ember that does not make any sense to me. I am not sure if this is a bug or feature. In the latter case I am really interested why this is a desired behavior. So here we go:

1. Make sure you can see your browsers console output.
2. Open the [example project on JS Bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/moxaxoda/4). Notice the two init messages comming from `IndexController` and `FoobarController`.
3. Click on the button saying 'Add one'. Do this so that there is some state on the `FoobarController`.
4. Click on the 'Go to hello' link to transition to the hello route
5. Go back to index via the link
6. The count variable still has the value. All good!

Now there is a [tiny change in the next JS Bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/moxaxoda/3). I pass the model to the render helper.
Follow the steps above again. After step 5 you see that count is 0 now and that the 'init FoobarController' appears again.

Somehow a controller belonging to a render helper gets reset when a model is passed. I can't find any information on why this happens or think of any reason why this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense to me! I guess this is the correct answer. P.S.: Refrence for the above is http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[From the Docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_render)**

> If a model property path is specified, then a new instance of the controller will be created and {{render}} can be used multiple times with the same name.

Passing that second param re-instantiates the `FoobarController`, which basically resets the count to 0, whereas not passing the model param creates a singleton instance of the `FoobarController`.

Comment: Answer seems to be correct, but I'm still not sure if this is a useful behavior. In my view render controllers should live as long as the others...would be a coherent behavior...but that is a question rather asked on http://discuss.emberjs.com/